# redirect with subdomain fails to register

Tags: .htaccess

I have several domains in which I have some rules in my .htaccess file to redirect a directory one level up such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^it/foo\.php$ https://www.example1.com/foo.php [R=301,L]
```

This works great. However I'm now trying to do the same thing with a subdomain or a different domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^it/foo\.php$ https://sub.example2.com/foo.php [R=301,L]
```

This redirect never happens. I though it may have something to do with the redirect to www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But even commenting this out gives the same problem. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

VirtualHost configuration is fairly basic and only for SSL:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName www.example2.com
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/.....crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/.....key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/.....ca-bundle
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT#2:**

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#CMS SEF stuff that's needed
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw|ini|zip|json|file|vcf))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^it/foo\.php$ https://sub.example2.com/foo.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I suspect `DocumentRoot` for example2 is different. Can you copy/paste `VirtualHost` entry of example2?

Comment: @anubhava No it's not. Same content with some subtle differences handled by a CMS.

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` entry of `example2`?

Comment: @anubhava added but I only have it for ssl.conf, not sure what that will tell you.

Comment: Hmm, can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://www.example2.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: @anubhava it says: /var/www/html - Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Ok can you post complete `/var/www/html/.htaccess` in question now.

Comment: @anubhava thanks again for looking. I stripped down everything other than the essentials. The only thing in there really is the SEF stuff needed for Joomla. But still no luck. This is very confusing.

Comment: Are you sure your RewriteRule before that, that rewrites certain stuff to `index.php`, hasn’t matched the request already? Because if it did, then `^it/foo\.php$` will not match any more …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
#CMS SEF stuff that's needed

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^it/foo\.php$ https://sub.example2.com/foo.php [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw|ini|zip|json|file|vcf))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Ugh, ordering all along. Thanks!